# how to decide which decision should be taken from four given options?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

For my snake AI, I'm using pytorch whose structure is:

```
class SnakeAI(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(24, 16, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(16, 8, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(8, 4, bias=True),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.fc(inputs)
        return x
```

Based on the inputs it gives me 4 values which to my understanding should be the probability of which decision to be, whose sum should be equal to 1. which is not the case here as the output is:

```
[0.59388083 0.5833764  0.47855872 0.5388371 ]
```

based on the given output should i use argmax to decide which direction to go with? is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your last layer to `nn.Softmax(-1)`. Then you would get in return a probability distribution and apply `torch.max()` which returns the maximum value and its index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torch.multinomial` to sample from a tensor.

You can also make it cleaner with `torch.distributions`.

```
from torch.distributions import Categorical
distribution = Categorical(x)
actions = distribution.sample(n) # gives you n samples from the distribution
```

This will give you more varies sampling compared to taking the max. `Categorical` will also adjust whenever values you put in to a probability distribution, so you don't need to worry about adjusting them.

The aspect brought up by the last user as to whether to use `softmax` or `sigmoid` is a more interesting one, and one that should be experimented with.

Using a `softmax` on your logits will always force one value to be large. Maybe this is what you want. However, it can cause funny things when all your logits are large or all your logits are small. If all your logits are small, this indicates the model has low confidence in all actions. However, passing that through a `softmax` will force one of those actions to have high probability.

Using a `sigmoid` approach can do a better job of showing the confidence in each action independent from one another. Again, something to experiment with.